# Getting the pdf from a Moment generating function

Tags: distributions, linear-model, moment-generating-function

I have to solve the following question:

> Let $X$ follow the distribution with moment generating function
>   $M_X(t)$ and Let $Y = aX + b$ follow the distribution with moment
>   generating function $M_Y(t)$.
>
> Show that $$M_Y(t) = e^{bt}M_X(at).$$

Now, I know that I need to find the density $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$ in terms of $f_X$ which is
$$f_Y = \frac{1}{a}f_X(\frac{y-b}{a}).$$
The question is, how do I identify the pdf of $f_X$ if it has not been stated in the problem what kind of distribution $X$ has?
Is there a generic pdf that can be used when the distribution of a random variable is not stated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the density to show that $M_Y(t) = e^{tb} M_X(at)$ (if it is your question).
By definition, the moment generating function of a random variable $X$ is:
$$
M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[ e^{tX} ]
$$

Since $Y= aX + b$ we have
\begin{align*}
M_Y(t) &= \mathbb{E} [ e^{tY} ] \\ 
&=\mathbb{E} [ e^{t(aX+b)} ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} [ e^{taX + tb} ] \\
&= \mathbb{E} [ e^{taX} e^{tb}]    \\
&= e^{tb}\mathbb{E} [ e^{taX} ] \ \ (\text{since} \ e^{tb} \ \text{is constant}) \\
&= e^{tb} M_X(ta)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:
$M_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{t(aX+b)}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{atX}e^b]=e^{tb}\mathbb{E}[e^{atX}]=e^{tb}M_X(at)$

If you wish, you can rewrite the mathematical expectations in terms of integrals over the pdf.